# segmentation fault with object instance and signal handler in vala

Tags: gtk3, vala

I'm writting a little http client to test api calls. This is the occasion for learning vala and using gtk3.

I made a class to deal with gtk interface and http request.

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;

public class RequestHandler : Object
{
    public string uri { get; private set; default = ""; }

    // Constructor
    public RequestHandler ()
    {
    }

    [CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
    public void on_url_changed (Entry entry, Button button)
    {
        stderr.printf ("this#%p\n", this);
        if (entry.get_text_length () == 0)
        {
            button.set_sensitive (false);
            this.uri = "";
        }
        else
        {
            button.set_sensitive (true);
            this.uri = entry.get_text();
        }
    }

    [CCode (instance_pos = -1)]
    public void on_send_clicked (Button button)
    {
        assert (this.uri != null );
        stderr.printf ("Send request to : %s\n", this.uri);
    }
}
```

The line

```
stderr.printf ("this#%p\n", this);
// => fprintf (_tmp0_, "this#%p\n", self); in the C file
```

display every time "this#0x1" and the program failed with segmentation fault at the line

```
this.uri = entry.get_text();
// _g_free0 (self->priv->_uri); in the C file
```

The UI is build with

```
var builder = new Builder ();
builder.add_from_file (UI_FILE);
var signals_handler = new RequestHandler ();
builder.connect_signals (signals_handler);
```

I'm really a newbie in vala and I don't see my mistake.

[edit]

```
...
<object class="GtkEntry" id="entry2">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
    <property name="hexpand">True</property>
    <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
    <property name="input_purpose">url</property>
    <signal name="changed" handler="request_handler_on_url_changed" object="button1" swapped="no"/>
</object>
...
```

The ui is fully generated with glade.

Comment: Please post your ui file...  I'm particularly interested in what signal you're trying to connect to on_url_Changed.

Comment: I just added the part of the UI file concerning the involved object.
By now I just changed the porterty to static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra argument on the on_url_changed method.  The [Gtk.Editable.changed](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Editable.changed.html) signal should have a single argument: the Gtk.Editable which changed.  Since there is no type safety with autoconnected signals, `public void on_changed (Gtk.Entry entry);` should work.

What is happening with the code you posted above is that something like this is being generated:

```
void request_handler_on_changed (GtkEntry* entry, GtkButton* button, RequestHandler* self) {
  fprintf (stderr, "this#%p\n", self);
}
```

And gtk+ is calling it like

```
request_handler_on_changed (editable, request_handler);
```

So, when your Vala code gets the information, it has the RequestHandler in the button argument, and self (which is how the "this" variable is generated) is garbage.

You have to be very careful when autoconnecting signals because you're basically circumventing Vala and hooking directly in to the generated C.  Vala has no way to provide type safety.

Comment: Thx, it's now work. So, I can't use "autoconnected signals" with instance method and extra agruments.

to bad.